# Creating an image contour (1) in a zero matrix, numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm using opencv to find contours of an object, the cuntours are in the the matrix of shape (7873, 1, 2)
(e.g. matrix zero below) in the form of [[[x1, y1]], [[x2, y2]], ...] whre x and y are indexes of pixels of an image.

Is it possible using numpy trickery to pass a list of all coordinates of the contour and change them to 1?
I'd like to avoid loops as this is time sensitive. Apart from numpy is there another time efficient way to do it?

```
zero = np.zeros((5, 5))
test = np.array([[[2,1]], [[3, 1]], [[1, 0]]])

zero[test] = 1
desired OUPUT (for this example): 
 x 0 1 2 3 4 
y _____________ 
0| 0 1 0 0 0 
1| 0 0 1 1 0 
2| 0 0 0 0 0 
3| 0 0 0 0 0 
4| 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
idx = test.reshape(-1,2).T
zero[idx[1], idx[0]] = 1
```